# How to store noise as a variable from the fourier transformation in python

Tags: python, fft

I am trying to perform Fourier transformation in python. And I would like to know, how to store the `noise` obtained from `Fourier transformation` as a `variable`?

Python code:

```py
import numpy as np

# Create a simple signal with two frequencies
dt = 0.001
t = np.arange(0,1,dt)
f = np.sin(2*np.pi*50*t) + np.sin(2*np.pi*120*t) # Sum of 2 frequencies
f_clean = f
noise = 2.5*np.random.randn(len(t))
f = f + noise              # Add some noise

## Compute the Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)

n = len(t)
fhat = np.fft.fft(f,n)                     # Compute the FFT
PSD = fhat * np.conj(fhat) / n             # Power spectrum (power per freq)
freq = (1/(dt*n)) * np.arange(n)           # Create x-axis of frequencies in Hz
L = np.arange(1,np.floor(n/2),dtype='int') # Only plot the first half of freqs

## Use the PSD to filter out noise
indices = PSD > 100       # Find all freqs with large power
PSDclean = PSD * indices  # Zero out all others
fhat = indices * fhat     # Zero out small Fourier coeffs. in Y
ffilt = np.fft.ifft(fhat) # Inverse FFT for filtered time signal
```

I have tried using the following lines of code to store the noise values, but not sure whether it is right syntax or approach to perform this task.

```py
## To store the noise using the PSD 

low_indices = PSD < 100   # Find all freqs with small power
PSDnoise = PSD * low_indices  # zero out larger freqs
fhat_noise = low_indices * fhat
```

Is there any better approach to store these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do

```
PSDnoise = PSD * low_indices
```

You will have `0` values where there was a `False` in `low_indices`.

If you just want to keep the values of `PSD` at indices where you're lower than your threshold, you can use array indexing, like so:

```
PSDnoise = PSD[low_indices]
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion and explanation.